# Window SizeToContent adds BlackBars till resize

Tags: c#, wpf

Good day everyone,

The issue I am running into is the following:

I have a Window with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` with an `ItemsControl` as content:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableColors, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="6" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <!-- Content in here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The expected result is that I have a window, which has the size of the `ItemsControl` plus the window border around is.

What I get though is the following:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JWe3laO.png]

Where does the black bar come from? As soon as I do a resize (on the Window) it snaps perfectly into place.

Thanks for your help.

Chris

Comment: your image is blocked can you display your image here within your question

Comment: Thank you Clemens for adding the picture. Couldnt do it yet due to low reputation.